# How to group the data in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, grouping

In my simple JS application I am in the need to display the data in an order.

**The flow:**

User choose sectors first, So we have Sector data based on user selection like,

```
const selectedSectors = [{sectorName: "Sector One", sectorId: 5}, {sectorName: "Sector Two", sectorId: 24}]
```

Then we already have a data of department and jobtitles and we are getting the matching records through the code,

```js
const selectedSectors = [{sectorName: "Sector One", sectorId: 5}, {sectorName: "Sector Two", sectorId: 24}]

const departments = [{"DepartmentID":51,"SectorID":5,"Name":"Production","SortOrder":1},{"DepartmentID":52,"SectorID":5,"Name":"Design/Engineering","SortOrder":2},{"DepartmentID":92,"SectorID":24,"Name":"Consulting","SortOrder":8},{"DepartmentID":114,"SectorID":24,"Name":"Administration","SortOrder":5}]

const jobTitles = [{"JobTitleID":167,"DepartmentID":51,"JobName":"Production Manager","Deleted":false,"SortOrder":5},{"JobTitleID":294,"DepartmentID":52,"JobName":"Senior Truss Designer","Deleted":false,"SortOrder":5},{"JobTitleID":178,"DepartmentID":51,"JobName":"Production Supervisor","Deleted":false,"SortOrder":3},{"JobTitleID":191,"DepartmentID":92,"JobName":"Saw Shop Supervisor","Deleted":false,"SortOrder":1},{"JobTitleID":461,"DepartmentID":114,"JobName":"Sawyer","Deleted":false,"SortOrder":7},{"JobTitleID":461,"DepartmentID":66,"JobName":"Sawyer","Deleted":false,"SortOrder":7},{"JobTitleID":474,"DepartmentID":92,"JobName":"Senior Truss Designer - Part Time","Deleted":false,"SortOrder":11},{"JobTitleID":449,"DepartmentID":51,"JobName":"Senior Wall Panel Designer","Deleted":false,"SortOrder":15},{"JobTitleID":278,"DepartmentID":114,"JobName":"Service Manager","Deleted":false,"SortOrder":2}]
    
    
const filteredData = departments.flatMap(department => {
const jobtitles= jobTitles.filter(
   (jobTitle) => jobTitle.DepartmentID === department.DepartmentID
);
  const newObj = {
      deptName: department.Name,
      jobtitles,
  };
 return newObj;
})

console.log('filteredData ', filteredData)
```

And the above code produces the below result like,

**Current Output:**

```
  [
   {
      "deptName":"Production",
      "jobtitles":[
         {
            "JobTitleID":167,
            "DepartmentID":51,
            "JobName":"Production Manager",
            "Deleted":false,
            "SortOrder":5
         },
         {
            "JobTitleID":178,
            "DepartmentID":51,
            "JobName":"Production Supervisor",
            "Deleted":false,
            "SortOrder":3
         },
         {
            "JobTitleID":449,
            "DepartmentID":51,
            "JobName":"Senior Wall Panel Designer",
            "Deleted":false,
            "SortOrder":15
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "deptName":"Design/Engineering",
      "jobtitles":[
         {
            "JobTitleID":294,
            "DepartmentID":52,
            "JobName":"Senior Truss Designer",
            "Deleted":false,
            "SortOrder":5
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "deptName":"Consulting",
      "jobtitles":[
         {
            "JobTitleID":191,
            "DepartmentID":92,
            "JobName":"Saw Shop Supervisor",
            "Deleted":false,
            "SortOrder":1
         },
         {
            "JobTitleID":474,
            "DepartmentID":92,
            "JobName":"Senior Truss Designer - Part Time",
            "Deleted":false,
            "SortOrder":11
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "deptName":"Administration",
      "jobtitles":[
         {
            "JobTitleID":461,
            "DepartmentID":114,
            "JobName":"Sawyer",
            "Deleted":false,
            "SortOrder":7
         },
         {
            "JobTitleID":278,
            "DepartmentID":114,
            "JobName":"Service Manager",
            "Deleted":false,
            "SortOrder":2
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

The above one is as expected based on the code written. And it filter the data of matching `DepartmentID` in `departments` and `jobtitles`. But I am missing out to display the data along with `Sectors`..

So user selects the `Sector` based on that the `department` and the department's `jobtitles` have to be displayed.

So I am expecting the level to be exactly like,

**Expected Output:**

```
[
   {
      "sectorid":5,
      "SectorName":"Sector One",
      "departments":[
         {
            "deptName":"Production",
            "jobtitles":[
               {
                  "JobTitleID":167,
                  "DepartmentID":51,
                  "JobName":"Production Manager",
                  "Deleted":false,
                  "SortOrder":5
               },
               {
                  "JobTitleID":178,
                  "DepartmentID":51,
                  "JobName":"Production Supervisor",
                  "Deleted":false,
                  "SortOrder":3
               },
               {
                  "JobTitleID":449,
                  "DepartmentID":51,
                  "JobName":"Senior Wall Panel Designer",
                  "Deleted":false,
                  "SortOrder":15
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "deptName":"Design/Engineering",
            "jobtitles":[
               {
                  "JobTitleID":294,
                  "DepartmentID":52,
                  "JobName":"Senior Truss Designer",
                  "Deleted":false,
                  "SortOrder":5
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "sectorId":24,
      "SectorName":"Sector Two",
      "departments":[
         {
            "deptName":"Consulting",
            "jobtitles":[
               {
                  "JobTitleID":191,
                  "DepartmentID":92,
                  "JobName":"Saw Shop Supervisor",
                  "Deleted":false,
                  "SortOrder":1
               },
               {
                  "JobTitleID":474,
                  "DepartmentID":92,
                  "JobName":"Senior Truss Designer - Part Time",
                  "Deleted":false,
                  "SortOrder":11
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "deptName":"Administration",
            "jobtitles":[
               {
                  "JobTitleID":461,
                  "DepartmentID":114,
                  "JobName":"Sawyer",
                  "Deleted":false,
                  "SortOrder":7
               },
               {
                  "JobTitleID":278,
                  "DepartmentID":114,
                  "JobName":"Service Manager",
                  "Deleted":false,
                  "SortOrder":2
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

As per the above given data, it is clear that the `sectorId: 5` has 2 separate departments `[Production and Design/Engineering]` and `sectorId: 24` has 2 separate departments `[Consulting and Administration]`..

```
const selectedSectors = [{sectorName: "Sector One", sectorId: 5}, {sectorName: "Sector Two", sectorId: 24}]

const departments = [{"DepartmentID":51,"SectorID":5,"Name":"Production","SortOrder":1},{"DepartmentID":52,"SectorID":5,"Name":"Design/Engineering","SortOrder":2},{"DepartmentID":92,"SectorID":24,"Name":"Consulting","SortOrder":8},{"DepartmentID":114,"SectorID":24,"Name":"Administration","SortOrder":5}]
```

I am able to filter the jobtitles array based on the DepartmentID and grouped it but I got stuck **to group the departments into each sectors based on sector id**.

**Hint** is `selectedSectors` and `departments` variables has the `sectorId` .

Kindly help me to achieve the above given expected result based on the inputs given.. A big thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    const selectedSectors = [{sectorName: "Sector One", sectorId: 5}, {sectorName: "Sector Two", sectorId: 24}]

    const departments = [{"DepartmentID":51,"SectorID":5,"Name":"Production","SortOrder":1},{"DepartmentID":52,"SectorID":5,"Name":"Design/Engineering","SortOrder":2},{"DepartmentID":92,"SectorID":24,"Name":"Consulting","SortOrder":8},{"DepartmentID":114,"SectorID":24,"Name":"Administration","SortOrder":5}]

    const jobTitles = [{"JobTitleID":167,"DepartmentID":51,"JobName":"Production Manager","Deleted":false,"SortOrder":5},{"JobTitleID":294,"DepartmentID":52,"JobName":"Senior Truss Designer","Deleted":false,"SortOrder":5},{"JobTitleID":178,"DepartmentID":51,"JobName":"Production Supervisor","Deleted":false,"SortOrder":3},{"JobTitleID":191,"DepartmentID":92,"JobName":"Saw Shop Supervisor","Deleted":false,"SortOrder":1},{"JobTitleID":461,"DepartmentID":114,"JobName":"Sawyer","Deleted":false,"SortOrder":7},{"JobTitleID":461,"DepartmentID":66,"JobName":"Sawyer","Deleted":false,"SortOrder":7},{"JobTitleID":474,"DepartmentID":92,"JobName":"Senior Truss Designer - Part Time","Deleted":false,"SortOrder":11},{"JobTitleID":449,"DepartmentID":51,"JobName":"Senior Wall Panel Designer","Deleted":false,"SortOrder":15},{"JobTitleID":278,"DepartmentID":114,"JobName":"Service Manager","Deleted":false,"SortOrder":2}]
        
        
    const filteredData = selectedSectors.map(sector =>  {
 const deps = departments.filter(dep => dep.SectorID === sector.sectorId).flatMap(department => {
    const jobtitles= jobTitles.filter(
       (jobTitle) => jobTitle.DepartmentID === department.DepartmentID
    );
      const newObj = {
          deptName: department.Name,
          jobtitles,
      };
     return newObj;
    })
return {
  sectorId: sector.sectorId,
  sectorName: sector.sectorName,
  departments: deps,
}
});

    console.log('filteredData ', filteredData)
```